# How to show and replace selector text even before fadeout is finished for each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which allows users to add a product to their shopping cart.

At the moment, when the "Add to cart" button is clicked, the selector is assigned text from Ajax data, the `#add-update` selector runs the Show() method then fadeOut() in 2.5 seconds, but if another click event was triggered before the end of the initial click fadeOut(), the product will be added to the cart, however the `#add-update` selector will not replace the existing text for the new product added until finishing the fadeOut().

I need the `#add-update` selector text to be updated on each click even before the end of a fadeOut() operation.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".add-item-to-cart").click(function () {
                // Get the id from the link
                var productIdToAdd = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/", { "id": productIdToAdd },
                    function (data) {

                        $('#add-update').text(data.Message);
                        $('#add-update').show();
                        $('#add-update').fadeOut(2500);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about chaining them with promises to do it after its finished?

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".add-item-to-cart").click(function() {
        // Get the id from the link
        var productIdToAdd = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.post("/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/", {
                "id": productIdToAdd
            },
            function(data) {

                $.when($('#add-update').text(data.Message)).then(function() {
                    $.when($('#add-update').show()).then(function(){
                      $('#add-update').fadeOut(2500);
                    });
                });
            });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than what I had. :) Although I have not come across promises before.